# Applescript run from menu bar?

Tags: applescript, menu-bar

I am aware of the Script Editor menu. That is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to run an Applescript from the menu bar? I can save it as a file and run it from the Script Editor menu, and I can save it as an application and stick it in my dock. Is there a file format that allows it to run from the menu bar, as many applications do? Or a way to edit the code that does the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cocoa-AppleScript as a script or AppleScript application created in Script Editor supports Menu Bar app. This script runs on macOS 10.12 (maybe runs on 10.10.x, 10.11.x). This script can be saved as application.

```
--AppleScript: menu bar script -- Created 2017-03-03 by Takaaki Naganoya
--2017 Piyomaru Software
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
--http://piyocast.com/as/archives/4502

property aStatusItem : missing value

on run
    init() of me
end run

on init()
    set aList to {"Piyomaru", "Software", "", "Takaaki", "Naganoya", "", "Quit"}
    set aStatusItem to current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s statusItemWithLength:(current application's NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    aStatusItem's setTitle:""
    aStatusItem's setHighlightMode:true
    aStatusItem's setMenu:(createMenu(aList) of me)
end init

on createMenu(aList)
    set aMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()
    set aCount to 1
    repeat with i in aList
        set j to contents of i
        if j is not equal to "" then
            set aMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:j action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"")
        else
            set aMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's separatorItem())
        end if
        (aMenuItem's setTarget:me)
        (aMenuItem's setTag:aCount)
        (aMenu's addItem:aMenuItem)
        if j is not equal to "" then
            set aCount to aCount + 1
        end if
    end repeat

    return aMenu
end createMenu

on actionHandler:sender
    set aTag to tag of sender as integer
    set aTitle to title of sender as string

    if aTitle is not equal to "Quit" then
        display dialog aTag as string
    else
        current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s removeStatusItem:aStatusItem
    end if
end actionHandler:
```

---

I previously edited the original *code*, posted by Piyomaru, just to the point it would compile and wanted to add some additional information to make the example *code* more useful for anyone relatively new to AppleScript.

Presently in the example *code*, if saved as an *application* it has no *code* to quit the *application*, it only removes the menu bar object. So, in the `actionHandler` *handler* of the *script*, add the following to the `else` *branch* of the `if` *statement*, after the existing *code*:

```
        if (name of current application) is not "Script Editor" then
            tell current application to quit
        end if
```

It's coded so if/when run from within Script Editor it will not attempt to close Script Editor. You can use it without the `if` *statement* block and use just `tell current application to quit` if you're not going to run it from within Script Editor.

Because this *script* is using Cocoa-AppleScript, once run from within Script Editor, it must be compiled again just before saving it in order to flush the C and Objective-C pointers created by the Cocoa-Applescript *code*, since pointers cannot be saved in the script. Just click the hammer icon on the Toolbar, or: Script Editor > Script > Compile   ⌘K

Additionally, when saved as an *application* you must check the **Stay open after run handler** *check-box* when saving it, and by default the app's Dock Tile will show in the Dock when running. As this might be unwanted behavior for a menu bar app, use the following *command* in Terminal to add the necessary *key* to the app's **Info.plist** file so it will not show in the Dock.

```
defaults write /Applications/name_of_app.app/Contents/Info.plist LSUIElement -bool yes
```

- Replace `name_of_app` with the actual name you saved it as, and if necessary change the path if not in `/Applications`.
- Note that if you drag the app to the Dock, its Dock Tile will still show on the Dock, just won't have a open indicator under it when open. This added *key* to the Info.plist file is to keep the Dock Tile from showing on the Dock when running, when the app has not been dragged to the Dock in the first place.

In the `actionHandler` *handler* of the original example *code*, it just displays a dialog box with the menu item number that was clicked, which certainly fine for example *code*, however, I'd like to show a different example how to have separate *code* execute based on which menu item was clicked. The following example *code* could replace the entire `actionHandler` *handler* in the original *script*:

```
on actionHandler:sender
    set aTitle to title of sender as string
    if aTitle is equal to "Quit" then
        current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s removeStatusItem:aStatusItem
        if (name of current application) is not "Script Editor" then
            tell current application to quit
        end if
    else if aTitle is equal to "Piyomaru" then

        --  # Your code to run for this menu choice goes here:

    else if aTitle is equal to "Software" then

        --  # Your code to run for this menu choice goes here:

    else if aTitle is equal to "Takaaki" then

        --  # Your code to run for this menu choice goes here:

    else if aTitle is equal to "Naganoya" then

        --  # Your code to run for this menu choice goes here:

    end if
end actionHandler:
```

Now this could be written differently, i.e. "Quit" as an `else` or `else if` at the bottom, but I did it this way because I want all other menu commands to be an `else if` choice, even though logically any other given menu command is more likely to be clicked then "Quit". For me, I think it's easier to add/edit/remove the menu command's *code* when written this way. It's just a personal preference, so do it as you feel what's right for you.

A discussion note from the AppleScript Language Guide:

> An *if* statement can contain any number of *else if* clauses; AppleScript looks for the first Boolean expression contained in an *if* or *else if* clause that is *true*, executes the statements contained in its block (the statements between one *else if* and the following *else if* or *else* clause), and then exits the *if* statement.
>
> An *if* statement can also include a final *else* clause. The statements in its block are executed if no other test in the *if* statement passes.

For the most part of the original example code, you should only have to modify two line of code in the `init` *handler*:

```
set aList to {"Piyomaru", "Software", "", "Takaaki", "Naganoya", "", "Quit"}
```

- This sets the name of the menu commands in their order, and `""` is for a separator.

For a different icon:

```
aStatusItem's setTitle:""
```

- Change the "" to something else you prefer, from: Script Editor > Edit > Emoji & Symbols

Hopefully it's obvious that the `if` statement block in the `actionHandler` *handler* will correspond to the `aList` in the `init` *handler*, so match the names in the `aTitle is equal to`  in the `actionHandler` *handler* to the names in the `aList` in the `init` *handler*.

The rest of the *code* should not need to be modified, although it certainly can if need be or wanted.

Comment: I edited your answer because as written is would not compile, it should now. Also, this script uses Cocoa-AppleScript, not normal or standard AppleScript alone. +1 though.

Comment: I can't save it - either as script or application.  I have done the compile step, but keep getting: The document "xxx" could not be autosaved. C and Objective-C pointers cannot be saved in scripts.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AppleScript document file can not save C and Objective-C pointers in it. So, you have to edit AppleScript (ex.add blank lines or delete blank lines), then you can save it. It is a normal operation for Apple genuine Script Editor.

Comment: My post is too much edited by other moderators without knowledge about latest AppleScript. Current version contains a lot of misunderstanding and not correct. 

So, I'll show the links to my articles on my blog. It works. 

http://piyocast.com/as/archives/996
http://piyocast.com/as/archives/1700
http://piyocast.com/as/archives/1851

Answer (score 7):

Normal AppleScript as a script or AppleScript application created in Script Editor is not supported as a Menu Bar app. You'd have to use Cocoa-AppleScript or build an app in Xcode (or use a third-party launcher) if you don't want to use the Script menu in the Menu bar.

Here's an example app done in Xcode using Swift: [WeatherBar](http://footle.org/WeatherBar/).

One long time trusted app that does this is [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), and although it's looks like the Scripts menu it does offer additional functionality. It can be run as a free app, up to 10 keyboard shortcuts, or upgraded for $9.95 to unlock unlimited keyboard shortcuts.

I have no affiliation with Red Sweater Software, LLC, other then as a user of FastScripts as a free app.

Comment: FastScripts is nice in that it lets you assign keyboard shortcuts for your menu items. Apple's "Script Editor menu" stopped letting you assign shortcuts to its menu items years and years ago,

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exactly you want to do with your apple script, maybe [xbar](https://github.com/matryer/xbar)/[swiftbar](https://github.com/swiftbar/SwiftBar) could be suitable for your purpose.

In general these applications lets you display the output of a variety of scripts in the menu bar - many scripts are already available but you can also write your own.

They can also be used to execute `applescripts`. I use them for example to execute an `applescript` saved as `service` by calling it through a little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "blub"
echo "---"
echo "1 | bash=/Users/username/Library/Services/Space_1 terminal=false"
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a little-used "Services" menu (in the menu under the application's name) and you can save scripts as services and make them available in the services menu for either a specific application .

There is also the concept of applications that are "attachable," these applications allow you to add scripts to the application's own menu commands. But applications that are attachable seem rare.

Does any of that fit what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope. I'm looking for an application that runs from the menu bar itself, not a service. Do you have the Speedtest app? Something like that, where the app itself is in the menu bar, not just launched from it.